# How does view creation on top of DBMS table using JDBC connection work internally?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Hope you are all doing well.
Can you please help me in understanding the difference between creating a view on top of a DBMS (SQL Server in my case) table using a JDBC connection and how it is different from actually reading the contents of the table, loading to a dataframe and creating the view on top of it.

**Create View on Top of SQL Server Table**

```sql
-- Please ignore the linebreaks, kept them for readability...

CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMP VIEW <VIEW_NAME> 
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc OPTIONS ( 
url "jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST_NAME>:<PORT_NUMBER>;database=<DATABASE_NAME>;", 
dbtable "(SELECT <COLUMNS> FROM <TABLE_NAME>) <ALIAS_NAME>", 
user "<USER_NAME>", 
password "<PASSWORD>")
```

**Create View on Top of Dataframe**

```scala
// Same query as above
val src_qry = "SELECT <COLUMNS> FROM <TABLE_NAME>"
// Assuming JDBC URL and Connection properties are available
val df_tbl = spark.read.jdbc(url = jdbc_url, table = src_qry, properties = jdbc_conn_prop)
df_tbl.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(<VIEW_NAME>)
```

1. How is each one different from the other and when is each option preferred ?
2. In the SQL option to create view, is the query result loaded to memory and then the view created on top of it ? How does it work internally ?
3. How do these options perform with higher volumes in the DBMS tables ? Is there any other alternate options available ?

Thank you for all the help in advance.
Cheers...

Comment: The first one creates a view in SQL server which will be accessible by all users that connect to that SQL server instance (based on permissions). The second command will create a temporary view within Spark that will be bound to the particular Spark Session it was created in and will get deleted as soon as the spark session is closed.

Comment: Hi, @philantrovert, thank you for your response. Can you please clarify ? The first one also should create the view in Spark only right ? I am able to access it in Databricks using `global_temp.view_name`. Also I checked in SQL Server, I could not find the view. Where does it get created ? If possible, can you also please confirm on the queries listed below ?